# jquery .hover() and .show()

Tags: jquery-hover

i want to  hide a `<div>` when mouse enters the `<div>` and it should reappear when mouse leaves the `<div>`.right now i just hid the `<div>` but it's not reappearing when mouse leaves the `<div>`

Comment: Just FYI, you want to use the formatting features when you post a question containing HTML. SO by default won't render those. It also makes it easier to read your question when you format it properly.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on @rob.alarcon's answer, you have to remember the API for the `.hover` method is:

```
hover( handlerIn(eventObject), handlerOut(eventObject) )
```

Since you didn't post your code, I can't give you a definite answer, but you need to remember to provide a handler for both the "hover in" and "hover out" events. Meaning, it sounds like you have a valid method to handle the event that is triggered when the mouse enters the element, but did you also provide an event handler for when the mouse leaves the element?

It's not something you want to do in a production site, obviously, but you could always throw an `alert()` message in both methods so that you know explicitly that the events are being handled.

HTH.